# Python class and method instantiation

Tags: python, class

Here is my code:

```
class calculator:

    def addition(x,y):
        added=x+y
        print(added)

    def subtraction(x,y):
        sub=x-y
        print(sub)

    def multiplication(x,y):
        mult=x*y
        print(mult)

    def division(x,y):
        div= x/y
        print(div)

calculator.addition(5,7)
```

This program gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/docs/defin_class.py", line 21, in <module>
    calculator.addition(6,3)
TypeError: unbound method addition() must be called with calculator instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I don't understand the mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

So without going too much into the nitty-gritty, you should add `@staticmethod` decorators above each function, like I've done below:

```
class calculator:

    @staticmethod
    def addition(x,y):
        added=x+y
        print(added)

    @staticmethod
    def subtraction(x,y):
        sub=x-y
        print(sub)

    @staticmethod
    def multiplication(x,y):
        mult=x*y
        print(mult)

    @staticmethod
    def division(x,y):
        div= x/y
        print(div)

calculator.addition(5,7)
```

The reason is that all of these methods are functions of the calculator, but they do not operate on an object of the calculator class.

For a great overview of the different types of methods you should use in Python, I highly recommend [this blog post](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods). Best of luck!